# Celery Task Succeeded but showing None in result

Tags: python-3.x, celery

```
from __future__ import division
from math import log, exp
from operator import mul
from math import e
from collections import Counter
import os
import pylab, json, csv
import pickle
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('sentiment_worker_test',backend='amqp', broker='amqp://localhost//')

pos = dict()
neg = dict()
features = set()
totals = [0, 0]
delchars = ''.join(c for c in map(chr, range(128)) if not c.isalnum())

CDATA_FILE = "countdata.pickle"

class MyDict(dict):
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if key in self:
            return self.get(key)
        return 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.train()
        # print "Trained..."

    def negate_sequence(self,text):
        """
        Detects negations and transforms negated words into "not_" form.
        """
        #some code 


    def train(self):
        #some code

    def classify2(self, text):
        #some code

    @app.task(bind=True)
    def classify_demo(self, input_data):
        #some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    query = "Some String to test"

    result = MyDict().classify_demo.delay(query)
    print (result.get())
    print
```

I am using this command to run celery task on my windows 7 pc:

> celery -A sentiment_worker_test worker -l info -P eventlet

it all displays and connected successfully...

but when i run this sentiment_worker_test.py file in another terminal with command:"python sentiment_worker_test.py"
then it shows "None" in result...

and at the celery command prompt window it shows following response..

> [2018-10-31 11:19:13,104: INFO/MainProcess] celery@dell-PC ready.
>   [2018-10-31 11:19:13,105: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: sentiment_worker_test
>   .classify_demo[4d173818-64f6-400a-a75b-344074921461]
>   [2018-10-31 11:19:13,107: WARNING/MainProcess] There is some error, please retry
>    with different input
>   [2018-10-31 11:19:13,108: INFO/MainProcess] pidbox: Connected toamqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//.
>   [2018-10-31 11:19:13,221: INFO/MainProcess] Task sentiment_worker_test.classify_demo[4d173818-64f6-400a-a75b-344074921461] succeeded in 0.10899999999946886s: None

I dont know what that warning means..."There is some error, please retry with different input"..
i have tried almost all different types of inputs...
but none worked...

any help would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are getting None in result in case of your decorated with app.task function do not return any value. Also, I bet this warning is coming from your code, probably from some print statement